# How to move labels in QGIS using the old labelling method

Tags: qgis

I would like to use the new labelling method in QGIS, however it does not display labels for all of my polygons. If I use the old labelling method (in the properties dialog) the labels display fine.

Is there an easy way to move labels using the old labelling method other than to specify a label coordinate in the table? I would like to be able to click on the label to move it like in the new label tool?

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/when-labelling-polygons-not-all-labels-are-displayed-qgis-1-7-0) asked about the problem I am having with the new labelling tool, but in this question I am interested in how to move labels using the old method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way using the old labeling method other than to specify a label coordinate in the table.

If you have troubles with labels not being displayed. You can allow colliding labels in new labeling engine settings.

Another thing if polygons still are not being labeled: Check if the geometries are valid. (Source: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4166)

Comment: I have enabled colliding labels in the new engines setting, and they still do not display.

Comment: Seems like you're experiencing the bug described in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/when-labelling-polygons-not-all-labels-are-displayed-qgis-1-7-0. Time for a bug report.

Comment: I shall submit one now.