# How to enforce labels for all polygons?

Tags: polygon, labeling, qgis-2

I am trying to label polygons but it does not always work.

Either the polygon is quite large, then the label appears, or the polygon is small, then the label is not displayed.

I've already tried to lower label size, disable box about overlap labels, disable scale limits, yet, nothing works.

If I want the label being displayed, I have to use the node tool in order to make the polygon larger ...  this is not the good solution.

Has someone already met this problem?
(I have looked [in other questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/when-labelling-polygons-not-all-labels-are-displayed-qgis-1-7-0?rq=1), but only polygons geometry validity is mentioned, and I have already checked it)

Comment: Could your share your data?