# Are there any options/plugins to allow labels in busy screens to be visible in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I have quite a busy screen, showing a large number of polygons in a small area. I would like each of these to be labelled neatly, without the 'crowded' feel of overlapping labels, as suggested in the article "[When labelling polygons, not all labels are displayed - QGIS 1.7.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/when-labelling-polygons-not-all-labels-are-displayed-qgis-1-7-0)".

[image]   [image]

Instead, I would like to see something as shown on the right (quickly sketched in Paint).

Can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Easy Custom Labeling` plugin.  When you move the labels though, save the layer to see the label moved to the end of the line (otherwise it looks like it is stall halfway along it).  Also note what it says about making a virtual layer!